# Cannot read properties of undefined when chaining methods

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to compare lists using an extension method that calls a comparer like so:

```
type HasDiff<T> = (object: T, row: any) => boolean;

 export const isListEqualToRows = <T>(objects: T[], rows: any[], hasDiffFunction: HasDiff<T>): boolean => {
  if (objects.length !== rows.length)
    return true;

  return rows.every((row, index) => {
    const object = objects[index];

    if (row.isNew) {
      return false;
    }

    return !hasDiffFunction(object, row);
  });
};
```

The comparison is being triggered by Angular's value changed in a ReactiveForm, not sure if relevant, but here's it:

```
import { isListEqualToRows } from '@core/helpers';

formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(debounceValue)).subscribe((changes) => {
  this.areChangesDetected = !isListEqualToRows<Person>(this.items, changes, this.hasDiff);
});
```

My issue is that for one object, I have a list within a list. So I'm trying to call the `isListEqualToRows()` method again inside:

```
hasDiff(item: Person, row: any): boolean {
  return item.description !== row.description
    || !isListEqualToRows<Address>(item.addresses, row.addresses, this.hasDiffAddress);
}

hasDiffAddress(item: Address, row: any): boolean {
  return item.AddressId !== row.id
    || item.AddressStreet !== row.street;
}
```

But I end up getting this error while running the second line of the `hasDiff()` method:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasDiffAddress')

How to solve this issue?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes! Also helped, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `hasDiff` without binding it to the correct `this` object. Since you have strict mode enabled, the `this` that `hasDiff` is referring to when invoked outside of a `someObject.hasDiff(...)` syntax is then `undefined` (without strict mode it would be the global object).

Instead of passing `this.hasDiff` to `isListEqualToRows`, you need to pass either `this.hasDiff.bind(this)` or `(item, row) => this.hasDiff(item, row)`.

<sub>Alternatively, add a `thisArg` argument to `isListEqualToRows` where you pass `this` from the caller's scope and then invoke `hasDiffFunction` as `hasDiffFunction.call(thisArg, object, row)` instead of `hasDiffFunction(object, row)`.</sub>

See also: [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)